# Run-times of sorted linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

What is the run time to find an element, insert an element, and remove an element in a sorted linked list?

I believe that they're all O(n) since you have to go through each link regardless. Am I right?

Comment: Check here http://bigocheatsheet.com/

Comment: @duncan sorted linked list is not on there

Comment: It will not change except now insert and delete need to find a specific element. This means they are doing the same thing as searching therefore they both become O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right. Think about it, regardless of whether or not you know the order of the nodes, the only way to actually access any node is to go through the node before it. That means for N nodes you have to go through N nodes making the operation O(N).

Comment: You only have to go through N/2 nodes. Thus sorted linked list belongs to the same complexity class yet with factors twice as low.

Comment: This is not true, remember that you only get O(N/2) or time complexities when we eliminate 2 nodes every time we traverse 1 node. This is not the case here. Every time we move through the list we only eliminate ONE node. Assuming the worst case scenario (which you have to consider) the time complexity is O(N). Remember that O(N) isn't always an average case, and instead you want to confidently say that the algorithm in question will not take longer than O(x) to complete!